Summation of two elements where the second one is recursively written as the sum of two other (sub)elements, then turn it into a random variable
Assume $x_r=x_1+x_2$, with $x_2=x_{21}+x_{22}$. Then, $x_r=x_1+x_{21}+x_{22}$. In turn, assume $x_{22}=x_{221}+x_{222}$, so $x_r=x_1+x_{21}+x_{221}+x_{222}$. Assume $x_{222}=x_{2221}+x_{2222}$. Then, $x_r=x_1+x_{21}+x_{221}+x_{2221}+x_{2222}$. That is, x_r is "decomposed" $n=4$ times.

How do I generalize this recursive operation into a summation formula with generic $n$ and with the simplest indexed notations?

Assume $x_1,x_2$ are joint normally distributed and correlated to each other. What is the vector of means and the variance-covariance matrix for $x_1,x_2,x_r$, given the recursive decomposition of $x_2$ where all its components are also normally distributed random variables correlated to each other and to $x_1$?


Question 2) might be confusing. According to @zwim comment, $X_r=X(1,1)+X(k,2)$, where $X(k,2)=X(k+1,1)+X(k+1,2)$. So before addressing 2), how do I model different probabilities for each $k-$realization? That is, there is a probability $p_1$ that $X_r=X(1,1)+X(k=1,2)$, a probability $p_2$ that $X_r=X(1,1)+X(k=2,2)$ and so on. Intuition: there are different probabilities for different degrees of "granularity" of my decomposition. Assume normal distributions.

What about using a two variables function with depth as parameter. I.e. $x_{2221}\mapsto X(4,1)$ and $x_{2222}\mapsto X(4,2)$. With $X(k,2)=X(k+1,1)+X(k+1,2)$ for all $k$ ?

$X_r=X_1+X(k,2)$?

for $k=1..n$? is it correct? Interesting idea, but how would I work out the distributions?

I edited my post using @zwim insight, in order to clarify an important aspect of the idea I am trying to formalize.
